# LINQ Code-First Select Using Composite Foreign Key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to perform a select based on one Entity with another entity as a foreign key relation.

I'm getting object back in my tests and they are the correct objects but for some reason I'm getting off failures in Asserts.  Sometime a related Entity is loaded and sometimes it isn't.

The LINQ code looks like:

```
var toDoList = _dbSet.Where(s => Context.ToDos.Where(std => std.UserId == userId && std.Id == s.Id).Any()).AsEnumerable();
```

The ToDo list contains an id for the entities I'm selecting from the _dbSet.  I'm wondering if this is related to lazy loading or problems with my LINQ.  How can I reliably get the related entities loaded as well?

Comment: I'm dubious about keeping a reference to a dbset as a member of the class.  Why do you need to do this?  Why not just reference your context to get it?

Comment: Might be related: AsEnumerable does not execute the query as ToList or ToArray would - it just converts it to IEnumerable but the execution is deferred until it is iterated.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that as soon as I posted this and amended my code.  I'm now immediately calling AutoMapper so all the properties are being initialised in that process.

Answer (score 0):

You can eagerly load related entities by using Include.

```
_dbSet.ToDos.Where(std => ...).Include(std => std.NavigationProperty)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

You can see this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) article for more information.